# Adobe Flash AS 2,0

Tags: flash, actionscript

Meu problema é que, quando o personagem se move na direção diagonal, ele não faz a animação (que é o mesmo do -x ou x).

*Eis o meu script:*

```
onClipEvent (enterFrame){
    if (Key.isDown(Key.UP)){
    this.gotoAndStop(2);
}
    if (Key.isDown(Key.DOWN)){
    this.gotoAndStop(1);

}
if (Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT)){
    this.gotoAndStop(4);
}
    if (Key.isDown(Key.LEFT)){
    this.gotoAndStop(3);
}
    if (Key.isDown(Key.UP) and Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT)){
    this.gotoAndStop(2);
    _root.char.costas.nextFrame();
}
if (Key.isDown(Key.UP) and Key.isDown(Key.LEFT)){
    this.gotoAndStop(2);
    _root.char.costas.nextFrame();
    }

        if (Key.isDown(Key.DOWN) and Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT)){
    this.gotoAndStop(1);
    _root.char.frente.nextFrame();

}
        if (Key.isDown(Key.DOWN) and Key.isDown(Key.LEFT)){
    this.gotoAndStop(5); 


}
}
```

Por favor, alguém poderia me dizer o que está errado?

Comment: Na verdade não há nada se mexendo aí. Você está alterando propriedades de uma timeline, o correto seria você utilizar as propriedades `x` e `y` do conteúdo que você quer que se mova. O que há dentro desses frames? Fica quase impossível detectar o que está ocorrendo no seu arquivo sem entender a parte gráfica.

Comment: meu o problema é so a animação que n trabalha

Comment: já conferiu a instancia dos moveclips se etá tudo certinho? Parece que ele só não anima quando vc aperta duas teclas ao mesmo tempo

Comment: obg mas eu n cosigo mandar imagens pois n tenho reputação soficiente..

Comment: ja conferi tudo